# Storyboard user defined runtime attributes with enum

Tags: ios, xcode, enums, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

Does anyone know if it's possible to set user defined runtime attributes in Xcode's storyboard with an enum's name (not value).

I tried String and Number types, neither of them works.
Setting it programatically is an option, I know.

In other words, for example I want to able to set the textAlignment attribute of UILabel to NSTextAlignmentCenter without knowing NSTextAlignmentCenter's real numeric value (1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible only if Xcode provides you with interface for that. For example, there're buttons to switch between NSTextAlignment for UILabel.

And, no, there's no way to set any `enum` values - as long as Xcode doesn't provide functionality like that for editing property lists.

It will become possible, when property lists will support enums